# Derivative of the Fourier transform of $c(x,t)^3$ w.r.t. $\hat{c}(k)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, fourier-analysis

I have the following non-linear ODE:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \hat{c}_\mathbf{k}}{\partial t} = f(\hat{c}_\mathbf{k}) = -k^2\left\{c^3 - c\right\}_\mathbf{k} - \kappa k^4\hat c_\mathbf{k}
\end{equation}
Which, by the way, is the discretised version of the Cahn-Hilliard equation using Fourier spectral methods. $\hat{c}_\mathbf{k}$ and $\{c^3 - c\}_\mathbf{k}$ denote the Fourier transform of $c(x,t)$ and $c^3 - c$, respectively.

My intention was to compute the Jacobian matrix (which, nicely, is diagonal) in order to compute its eigenvalues and study the stability of the ODE. So we have:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f(\hat{c}_\mathbf{k})}{\partial \hat{c}_\mathbf{k}} = -k^2\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{c}_\mathbf{k}}\left\{c^3\right\}_\mathbf{k}-1\right) - \kappa k^4
\end{equation}
Now, all I have left to do is compute the derivative of $\{c^3\}_\mathbf{k}$ w.r.t. $\hat{c}_\mathbf{k}$, but this is where it gets tricky. I think (this was verified through numerical means) that the result is (a $\times 3$ factor might be missing though):
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{c}_\mathbf{k}}\{c^3\}_\mathbf{k} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\{c^2\}_\mathbf{k}
\end{equation}
but I cannot figure out how exacly one finds this result analytically. Here's my complete development, up until I get stuck:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{c}_\mathbf{k}}\{c^3\}_\mathbf{k} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{c}_\mathbf{k}}\{c \cdot c^2\}_\mathbf{k}\\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{c}_\mathbf{k}}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\hat{c}_\mathbf{k} \,* \{c^2\}_\mathbf{k}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{\partial \hat{c}_\mathbf{k}/\partial k}\frac{\partial}{\partial k}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\hat{c}_\mathbf{k} \,* \{c^2\}_\mathbf{k}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}*\{c^2\}_\mathbf{k} \\
??&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\{c^2\}_\mathbf{k}
\end{align}
The previous was obtained using the convolution property of the Fourier transform, as well as the derivative of a convolution. I know there must be a mistake somewhere in there, but I don't know where and I don't know how to prove the result either...

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: Is $\hat{c} = c_k$ here? Was a bit confusing with two symbols for the same thing. "I know (this was verified through numerical means)" How did you check this numerically? Just naively deriving this from the definition I would have guessed $\frac{d(c^3)_k}{dc_{k'}} = \frac{3}{2\pi}(c^2)_{k-k'}$.

Comment: You're right, I edited my post to fix the notation !
And by verifying, I meant that I solved the ODE using an Implicit Euler scheme in conjunction with a Newton-Raphson iteration, for which I need the jacobian of the ODE. The correct solution was obtained for the result I mention in my post, leading me to believe this was the correct derivative...

Comment: The naive derivation I was thinking off was: $(c^3)_k \equiv \int dx\, c^3(x)e^{-ikx}$ and $c(x) \equiv \int\frac{dk}{2\pi}\, c_k e^{ikx}$ so using $\frac{\partial c_k}{\partial c_{k'}} \equiv \delta(k-k')$ we have $\frac{\partial c(x)}{\partial c_k} = \frac{e^{ikx}}{2\pi}$ and therefore $\frac{\partial (c^3)_k}{\partial c_{k'}} = \int dx\, 3c^2(x)\frac{\partial c(x)}{\partial c_{k'}}e^{-ikx} = \frac{3}{2\pi}(c^2)_{k-k'}$. But its so long ago I worked on similar stuff its possible I have messed up some definitions here.

Comment: This somewhat makes sense to me, though I'm not sure what $\{c^2\}_{k-k'}$ represents compared to $\{c^2\}_k$...?
And there's still the fact that my code points to $\frac{1}{2\pi}\{c^2\}_k$ being the correct answer,  although it's entirely possible I messed up somewhere...

Comment: It represents $(c^2)_k$ evaluated at wavenumber $k-k'$ (since the underlying PDE is non-linear ). So if you need $\frac{\partial (c^3)_k}{\partial c_{k}}$ then would just be $\frac{3}{2\pi}(c^2)_{k=0}$, i.e. its given by the DC mode of $c^2$.